# Is this a counterexample to problem 5-17 in John Lee's Intro to Topological Manifolds?

Tags: geometric-topology

I believe I have a counterexample to Problem 5-17 in John Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*.  Can someone please confirm that it is a counterexample or explain why it isn't? Here is the statement of the problem.

"Suppose $\sigma = [v_0, \ldots, v_k]$ is a simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  If $\{w, v_0, \ldots, v_k\}$ is an affinely independent set, we say that ***w is affinely independent of $\sigma$***.  In this case, the simplex $[w,v_0, \ldots, v_k]$ is denoted by $w \ast \sigma$ and is called the ***cone on $\sigma$***.  More generally, suppose $K$ is a finite Euclidean simplicial complex and $w$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is affinely independent of every simplex in $K$.  Define the ***cone on $K$*** to be the following collection of simplices in $\mathbb{R}^n$:  $w \ast K = K \cup \{[w]\} \cup \{ w \ast \sigma : \sigma \in K \}$.  Show that $w \ast K$ is a Euclidean simplicial complex whose polyhedron is homeomorphic to the cone on $|K|$."

My counterexample is motivated by Munkres' definition of the cone on $K$, in which it is required that the ray from any point $p$ in $K$ to $w$ intersect $K$ only at the point $p$.  Let $e_0=0$, and let $(e_1,e_2)$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the boundary of the standard $2$-simplex $\Delta_2 = [e_0, e_1, e_2]$, $\partial \Delta_2 = \{[e_0,e_1], [e_0,e_2], [e_1,e_2]\}$, which is a $1$-dimensional Euclidean simplicial complex in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Let $w=(1,1)$.  Then $w$ is affinely independent of every simplex in $\partial \Delta_2$, but, for example, $w\ast[e_0,e_1] \cap [e_1,e_2]$ is not a face of either simplex, as it is the lower half of $[e_1,e_2]$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

(Addition -- 5/26/2017) Thank you guys for your comments.  It seems that the additional assumption that, for any $\sigma \in K$, $(w \ast \sigma) \cap |K| = \sigma$ is needed, where $|K|$ is the polyhedron of $K$.  It is sufficient, and here I think is a brief argument that it is necessary.  Suppose $w \ast K$ is a Euclidean simplicial complex.  Let $q \in (w \ast \sigma) \cap |K|$, say $q \in \tau$, where $\tau \in K$.  Then $q \in (w \ast \sigma) \cap \tau \neq \varnothing$, so $(w \ast \sigma) \cap \tau$ is a face of both $\tau$ and $w \ast \sigma$.  The only faces of $\tau$ are simplices in $K$, and the only faces of $w \ast \sigma$ that are simplices in $K$ are faces of $\sigma$, so $q$ is in some face of $\sigma$. Thus $(w \ast \sigma) \cap |K| \subset \sigma$, and the other inclusion is immediate.  The counterexample then shows that this additional assumption isn't implied by the existing assumptions.

Comment: The set $\{w, e_0, e_1, e_2\}$ is not affinely independent, by cardinality alone.

Comment: (Also, the second $1$-simplex in $\partial \Delta_2$ should be $[e_2, e_0]$, not $[e_0, e_2]$.)

Comment: @Travis: I think the OP is correct, assuming that the quotation is accurate. When the definition that is given in that quotation is applied to the simplicial complex $K=\partial\Delta_2$ in the following paragraph of the question, it is not required that $\{w,e_0,e_1,e_2\}$ be affinely independent, only that $w$ be affinely independent of the simplices in $\partial\Delta_2$, namely of $[e_0,e_1]$, and of $[e_0,e_2]$, and of $[e_1,e_2]$, which it is.

Comment: @LeeMosher Hmm, after reading more carefully, I think you're right. FWIW (1) I checked my copy and the quotation here appears correct, and (2) this does not appear in Lee's errata to the text: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/Manifolds/errata.pdf

Comment: Thanks to @LeeMosher and the OP for pointing this out. I've added it to my [correction list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ITM/).

Comment: @JackLee Thank you for your outstanding textbooks.  I've read and continue to read all three of them religiously.

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks for the kind compliment.